# Technical question on stats in ff7

Tags: final-fantasy-7

I have the following question on stats in final fantasy 7 (=ff7).

I have Cloud on lvl 99 with 255 strength (ignoring armor and weapons and materia). Now I noticed the following:
I can still give cloud power sources (which increase strength) but this only works to a certain point and then it is not possible anymore. One can give around 100 more power sources and then it is not possible anymore. Is there a precise explanation why it is not possible anymore?

I dont know but my own explanation would be that the real max of stats in ff7 is 355 and not 255 and one can go up to 355 despite that the displays max is 255. (for example ruby has 355 defense)

Answer (score 1):

> **Marking this as community wiki as it's converting a comment to an answer**

According to a comment from Frank, the answer is:

> Basically, implementation counts how many sources used, and caps it at 255, and adds to base value, which is capped at 99. You can use 100 more sources because not everyone's stats will hit 99 by level 99.

[Source](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/197341-final-fantasy-vii/50767586)

Comment: 255 is a common maximum value for programmers to use since it the max value of a 8 bit integer.